# How to run SDL 2.0 project setup executable using DOSBox?

Tags: sdl, dosbox

I am newbie to SDL and developed a small SDL 2.0 project, trying to run setup under dosbox but it crash.

Comment: Back in the DOS days, there were no OS standards for device drivers - they gave you access to the underlying hardware and that was it (not putting M$ code between your code and an 8MHz 8086 was seen as a good thing). That meant, for example, writing handlers in your code for every printer you supported! SDL uses OS standard drivers to abstract out hardware acceleration etc for video cards which DOS does not have. Since it's open source, you could (in theory) write a DOS version of SDL but without hardware acceleration in an emulator, it might be really slow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. If you want to run your app with SDL forget about DOS: DOS is *not* on [the list of supported platforms](http://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation#Supported_platforms).